# Vk Api. Vk Upload не загружает фотографии в группу

Tags: python, вконтакте

```
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = token)
vkApi = vk_session.get_api()

upload = VkUpload(vkApi)
upload.photo_wall(photos = r"C:\Users\...",
        group_id=2018#####,
        caption="test")
```

В общем, вот кусочек кода. Проблема в том, что без какого-либо **exception**, итерация проходит, а картинка в группу не публикуется.

У меня до этого получалось щитпостить с помощью собственной страницы, но сейчас хотелось бы делать то же с токеном группы. Вот. Заранее спасибо

Может быть в вашей практике использовались другие методы? Я не против попробовать другие варианты. Меня только удивляет, что **токен сообщества** не работает, а **Standalone-приложения** - вроде работает. По-крайней мере, ошибку не выкидывает.

Answer (score 0):

```
vkApi.wall.post(owner_id= -id,
            message= message,
            attachment = attachments,
            publish_date = publish_date)
```

Использовал [wall.post](https://vk.com/dev/wall.post)